# MYSQL and CI Array Of Data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

In one of my controllers to fetch all the data for my general view page I use a foreach loop and then `$object->column_name` but now I have decided I would like to do a couple of things with this data:

- Edit it -> It is an edit page for each `$object` by its `$id`
- Use the `$object->name` field via the controller to enable me to use it in a `$data['pageTitle']= Edit '.$object->name.';`

What would be the best way to change the model below so that I can use it for many purposes / different ways of displaying the data for manipulation?

```
public function showAll()
{

    $database = $this->db->get('form');

    if($database->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $database->result();
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Comment: A non-crucial note: What would be the point of your $rows variable there?

Comment: @Atli its sitting there for show as I have just found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to keep the database query part in your model rather than the controller.

In your controller you can do something like:

```
$recs = $this->sample_model->model_function();
foreach ($recs as $r)
{
    $r->additional_info_appended_to_each_row = 'whatever';
}
```

This way you can append an additional variable to each database row for displaying / editing etc.

Comment: 1. I know but I am wanting to know is there a better way that I could write my model to allow for more flexibility?

Comment: hmm could you precisely describe the "flexibility" ?

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't really show us enough of the relevant code to be able to answer that question. Assuming `$database->result()` returns an array of rows (a database query's result set) then the data it contains depends on how the query looks. All you show is is `$this->db->get('form')`, which can mean just about anything.

A generic answer to your question would be: Alter the SQL query to include the id and name fields. Then inject those into your view through your controller. (Or get them directly through the view. That's up to you.)

Not knowing a thing about your controllers or your views, here is an example that assumes your views extend the Smarty template engine.

```
public function GeneralController
{
    public function defaultAction()
    {
        $model = new GeneralModel();
        $objects = $model->getAll();

        $view = new GeneralView();
        $view->assign("objects", $objects);
        $view->show();
    }
}
```

The Smarty template would then use those rows when generating the HTML

```
{foreach $objects as $object}
<section class="object">
    <header>
        <h1>{$object->name}</h1>
    </header>
    <p>{$object->contents}</p>
    <footer>
        <a href="/general/edit/?id={$object->id}">Edit</a>
    </footer>
</section>
{/foreach}
```